# Typescript narrowing type with generic error

Tags: typescript, generics

Can someone help me understand what is going on here: [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwDwHkzAJYHsB2AzgHxQC8UA3gLABQUUA2gNJTb5QDWEIuAZlEw4ChALoAuKACUIcACYEANiFQ16DNnMnMANHQ1RcWPEUlCThFqL3qAvsTq3G3XgPMjRAbjp12wCAh8cADG0ADKwLgIEBjGIqRqBhAAHhDBkgAU+CnAEXD+kvBIaO5ExACU5KQAbrjYco4+tKCQsIgQ+MClhORU+hoA5HADkpRQcJKEwAjsAOZQtja2UABkUGEArgBG3U0t4dvdvYmDWyNUUFuS+BvIWwELS018G-jBwhz+Uxn9DGDtnQAYopcAB3ACiqXSUCyOTyBTaxVQRQ6XTiZUqZBqdTkNgMhG2wLBkLSmWyyVywHyEEKiBQqE2O3RJEx2PqeI0vyg-2inQAcgQAOIdALYaFjFKkmHkynU2lIlGdboVKpQWr1R5cglbAX4YXZGbiqCS6GwinwmmI+mM5WstU4zXqBhcnmoomgyQRKIxRVoj4kDkMbXuz2RaIMw7M4iBqB0SonP4A4DuknBXrBkEQqGeKAAelzxoQCCiklwnC1hMzqd6rqBVezeYL-0IhAgDVoLqTuv1orTFG13ZFhpz+cLxYQpfLTqgA6FQ7FNa7c4NYpHTbgLbbTQMteTmfTlbBa7HJcMU-xh9Bi95e6PjZPCCgAH4n9uNKOAJLcxRwT64KAbK2bDAFAijYNwUDAAAFtghAVlsMDFqELYZLu7rlN4tC2M8rzvCYM7bIhuDIYQGR8JmXrRKG3oRky-oqgmUDkWClEQAAdCaGRjPUkhDAMOiGMyozjLxwwLAsGH3sEv4DCB0mKIoUCgtg0FQHxXLMaCrEcVCXGaLxZwCUY-rCVcUAAMzibYkmjmWjhAA)

basically I have a `store` that has an `exec` method, I want to narrow the type of `exec` param for a sub process
But there seems to be an error with the store type being a generic type

```
type Param<Options> = {
  [K in keyof Options]: Readonly<{
    id: K,
    options: Options[K],
  }>
}[keyof Options];

interface Store<Options> {
    exec: (nextState: Param<Options>) => void
}

type ParentOptions = {
    'a': { a: string },
} & SubOptions

type SubOptions = {
    'b': { b: number },
}

function test(
    parentFlowExec: (nextState: Param<ParentOptions>) => void,
    subFlowExec: (nextState: Param<SubOptions>) => void,
    
    parentNonGeneric: { exec: (nextState: Param<ParentOptions>) => void },
    subNonGeneric: { exec: (nextState: Param<SubOptions>) => void },
    
    parentFlow: Store<ParentOptions>,
    subFlow: Store<SubOptions>,
    
) {
    parentFlowExec = subFlowExec; // error: ok
    subFlowExec = parentFlowExec; // passed

    parentNonGeneric = subNonGeneric; // error: ok
    subNonGeneric = parentNonGeneric; // passed

    parentFlow = subFlow; // error: ok
    subFlow = parentFlow; // error ??

    // I plan to use it like this
    subProcess(parentFlow);
}

function subProcess(flowStore: Store<SubOptions>) {
    flowStore.exec({ id: 'a', options: { a: 'a' } }); // can't call with 'a'
    flowStore.exec({ id: 'b', options: { b: 3 } }); // ok
}
```

Update:
I moved the Param out and have [it working](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwDwHkzAJYHsB2AzgHxQC8UA3gLABQUUA2gNJTb5QDWEIuAZlEw4ChALoAuKACUIcACYEANiFQ16DNnMnMANHQ1RcWPEUlCThFqL3qAvsTq3G3XgPMjRAbjp12wCAh8cADG0ADKwLgIEBjGIqRqBhAAHhDBkgAU%20CnAEXD%20kvBIaO5ExACU5KQAbrjYco4%20tH4BQaFQEVEQAEyxwmVU%20hopaZnZybnA%20RBmcUSVZDV1DbS2TaCQsIgQ%20MClhOSD6gwA5HAnkpRQcJKEwAjsAOZQtja2UABkHQCuAEb763A4T%20%200OiQ0J1%20FyoUF%20knw32QvwCLzeTT433wwX6UH8dwyQwYYG2uwAYopcAB3ACiqXSUCyOTyBS2xVQRR2ezmJAWS3qNgMhD%205KptNGDPGk2mhUQKFQYRB3IqVSgtX5hKgGuJ0V2ADkCABxHYBbD0q4jemMibMmasuUc3b7ZWLVXLVEaoW-fX4I3ZB5mqAWsZMqYsopyhX-JW8131d3HTUJ7WckWUySdaLsklc-okAUaT2p9ORTORp35hha7PdYtdXrhtAOnMWYjECtQT01jolnpZtllpVtuiVcFE7OpsXBQ6Fik0umeKAAekXgYQCCiklwnA9wtnk8OybJe-nS5XxMIhAgKyrOuA3t9JqnFE99%20N-oXy9X64Qm%203CZfhpvqaB7Zq%20fqmh%20Z5wBeV5NAYh7AKm067lSkFfhuhh-oKKGUiBt6pmhATflAAD8JFwRoCHdMhvzdN4-5-NRFBUfRGqfgAklAYCKHAHCRFA3yXmwwBQIo2DcLiAAW2CEDuvwwOuoQXhkCGpuU9EGGxK6UlEnBPHJCm4EphDdCp1bqY0tB0BiWI4p6hnGRkfCzhmtqufKiq5sqo5QM5VKuQAdBaGRXPUkhnCcOiGNylzXOF5wvC86mnlAwS8ScIlpYoihQJS2DAJJUARRqfmUoFwWhVoRVQlFRi5rFcJQAAzIltjJZ%20W6WTZ2ImB2fwORAF6maVrm1tE9aymgA5ed5JUuT2QV0iFmjxZF0X1TCNxFQl7xtWhaX4BlqVwNluX5YVxUJiNC0VSt1VrXVFgNZILW7e1K6dasQA) but still don't understand why nested them doesn't work

```
interface Store<Options> {
    exec: (nextState: Options) => void
}
// parent2: Store2<Param<ParentOptions>>,
// sub2: Store2<Param<SubOptions>>,
```

Comment: I believe that it is because `subFlow` and `parentFlow` are invariant to each other. See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc

Comment: thank you @captain-yossarian I understand a thing or two about these variants today.

to my understanding, both `Store<T>` and `Param<T>` are contravariance, nested them somehow doesn't work (I don't see how it creates an invariance)

so I made it working by moving it out: `Store<Param<Options>>`

Comment: These  are hard topics for me,  invariance - was just an asumption :)

Comment: Try this solution https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwDwHkzAJYHsB2AzgHxQC8UA3gLABQUDUA2gNJTb5QDWEIuAZlEw4ChALoAuKACUIcACYEANiFQ16jTdnlSWAGjqbNuLHiJThZwqzEGNDAL7E6Dpjz6DLosQG46dUEgoAGVgXAQIDFNRUgp1TQgADwgAYwlUABVyIWiiYgAKfCTgULhgCCl4JDQM4gBKclIAN1xtF39aQOgqiHxgLyJs+MYAcjgRqUooOClCYAQOAHMoBzsHKAAyEIBXACMBwg6unf3cwiHDUd2JqihdqXxt5F2IBBW1jv5t-BSRTnK5vlLgwwIhesAAGJKXAAdykoXCkR6fQOxDsdAawwYhD2MAQuBSEEIhHyoIifShsIAdElUnU-LQHJ9vr8zFAcbs8QSiSTaWkoKgAKpQYq9eTnYJ7VGFYqlcqVRAoIX1RpQFraTHAkXJFL5KbaKQja56KAmP6ESZ3KQAZhWK3pUAA9I7TVwXEA

Comment: Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH49aarW6sU you can find good video about contravariance in TypeScript

Comment: Offtopic. In Scala you can decide whether generic parameter should be covariant, contravariant or invariant. There is nice syntax for invariance : `class Foo[-A]`

Comment: @captain-yossarian I think there is a pending proposal for adding variance markers for generic parameters. Will link to it when I dig it up (if no one bears me to it).

Comment: @captain-yossarian - ah, yes, here it is: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10717

Comment: @OlegValter unfortunately they don't have it in roadmap (

Comment: @captain-yossarian - yeah, that's true, just wanted to resurface it for the benefit of the readers + the more exposure the better (and Ryan mentioned they are still looking into it). I don't know if explicit variance annotations are a good way to go, but they would nicely solve the OPs problem for sure

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, first, let's quickly recap what different "variance" means. In the following table, I am using definitions from Microsoft's [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) (except for bivariance that's not in the docs) since I find them the easiest to grasp:

| Variance | Meaning | Allowed substitutions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bivariance | Covariance and Contravariance at the same time | Supertype -> Subtype, Subtype -> Supertype |
| Covariance | Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified | Supertype -> Subtype |
| Contravariance | Enables you to use a less derived type than originally specified | Subtype -> Supertype |
| Invariance | Means that you can use only the type originally specified | none |

Let's check which one of your types is a supertype and which is a subtype:

```ts
type T1 = SubOptions extends ParentOptions ? true : false; // false
type T2 = ParentOptions extends SubOptions ? true : false; // true
```

It follows that the `PartentOptions` is a subtype of `SubOptions`, while the latter is its supertype. What does it tell us? It tells us that when you annotate `subFlow` as `Store<SubOptions>` and then try to assign `parentFlow` to it (annotated as `Store<ParentOptions>`), you are trying to assign a *subtype where a supertype is expected*.

If we refer to the variance table, we will see that this requires *covariance*, but as you get an error, this means we are dealing with either *contravariance* or *invariance*. Now, when you assign `subFlow` to `parentFlow`, you are assigning a *supertype where a subtype is expected*.

The above also results in an error, meaning the assignment here is actually *invariant*, and [@captain-yossarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482793/typescript-narrowing-type-with-generic-error#comment119279210_67482793) is correct:

> I believe that it is because subFlow and parentFlow are invariant to each other.

This behavior, however, is a design limitation of TypeScript (see Anders Hejlsberg's [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32674#issuecomment-716178615) on the related issue) sacrificing some flexibility for soundness (remove the `[keyof Options]` indexing, and you will see that the contravariant assignment becomes possible).

As for your solution, due to how variance analysis works, when you move the `Params` outwards, the parameter types become *covariant* (as `T[keyof T]` is not aliased here. Note that when reduced to the bare structure, the `Param` type is exactly that: `type Param<Options> = Options[keyof Options]`, only mapped<sup>1</sup>).

Take a look at a simplified example<sup>0</sup> of your solution:

```ts
type Param<Options> = {
  [K in keyof Options]: Readonly<{
    id: K,
    options: Options[K],
  }>
}[keyof Options];

interface Store<Options> {
    exec: (nextState: Options) => void
}

type SuperOptions = { 'b': { b: number } }
type SubOptions = { 'a': { a: string } } & SuperOptions

const test1 = (subtype: Store<Param<SubOptions>>) => subProcess1(subtype); // OK, Subtype -> Supertype, covariance
const test2 = (supertype: Store<Param<SuperOptions>>) => subProcess2(supertype); // error, Supertype -> Subtype, contravariance

const subProcess1 = (supertype: Store<Param<SuperOptions>>) => supertype.exec({ id: 'b', options: { b: 3 } }); // ok
const subProcess2 = (subtype: Store<Param<SubOptions>>) => subtype.exec({ id: 'b', options: { b: 3 } }); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Eu778wUApbeiXgnOB4PBUOaCMDaPAoYjSTJ2ap9Hp3CcIA)

---

<sup>0</sup> Your naming choice slightly adds confusion to an already tough problem: a subtype is called `ParentOptions` and supertype `SubOptions`, while the relationship between them is the opposite, so I named them `SubOptions` and `SuperOptions` accordingly to make things clearer.

<sup>1</sup> From the discussion in comments, it must be noted that while the relationship between `Store<Param<SubOptions>>` and `Store<Param<SuperOptions>>` in the solution is *covariant*, `T[keyof T]` here is *contravariant* (see Anders's [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32674#issuecomment-716192565) - the `SuperOptions` supertype has fewer properties than the `SubOptions` subtype, and there is no discriminant).

Comment: I find your table and explanation very useful. I wish I could donate you 100 of my reputation :) Thanks for all links. It is hard to find good article about variance/covariance etc. Super answer!

Comment: @captain-yossarian - thank you (although only 1/3 of the table is my effort :))! The information fragmentation is immense nowadays :) It took me quite a while to uncover Anders's comment which effectively explains what's going on here. Btw, what I didn't expect is to actually get invariance - my initial thoughts revolved around covariance because subtyping seems sound enough in this case.

Comment: @captain-yossarian - it was easy to find as soon as I became convinced the relationship is actually that of invariance :) But it took a while to get there. Btw, thanks for linking the Berlin meetup video above - I don't usually watch YT talks, but Titian's talk on variance was superb.

Comment: I watched his talk twice or even more, until I understood the topic :D

Comment: regarding the answer: `when you move the Params outwards, the parameter types become covariant (as T[keyof T] is not aliased here`: I think mine is contravariance, If you see Anders Hejlsberg's next comment, T[keyof T] variant type depends on T, and that's why when I move it outward and feeding it a concrete type, it becomes contravariance (in my case) and passes the type check. On the other hand, feeding it with a generic `Options` is not enough and it can only assume that it's invariance (although we do have a concrete type at the end but I guess this is where the performance limitation is)

Comment: @Tubc - gosh, when will I stop messing up playground links... I think I understand what you mean, but if the relationship is contravariant then the tests passing subtype where supertype is expected (`test1`) and supertype where subtype is expected (`test2`) do not make sense to me. This should be easy to confirm: https://tsplay.dev/w8vypm. If they were contravariant, the error order would be inversed during assignment. Maybe we are talking about different things, though - I was referring to the relationship between two `Store<Options>`.

Comment: @OlegValter to my understanding, `Param<T>` and `Store<T>` are both contravariance, putting them together the final type is covariance `test1`. In `test2` doesn't work because `Param<T>` is nested inside, and due to missing T type information `Param<T>` become invariance (like mentioned before, we do have T type at the end, but according to Anders Hejlsberg's comment `If type relations were fully evaluated structurally at all times we'd get the expected results` so TS just doesn't do that and assume it's invariance)

Comment: this demonstrates my understanding: https://tsplay.dev/wRpqLm

Comment: @Tubc - I was away by the time you commented - let me review the playground and get back to you as soon as I have a grasp of what's going on there. Judging from skimming it, I think we are not in disagreement, but I should word the part about aliasing better and expand. `Param<T>` is indeed contravariant, so is the `Store<T>`. However, in "parameter types become covariant" I refer to the relationship between `Store<Param<SuperOptions>>` and `Store<Param<SubOptions>>` which is confirmed to be covariant in both your and my playgrounds.

Comment: @Tubc - as for the other comment Anders made - yeah, I analyzed it, but decided not to include it to avoid causing even more confusion. Your case certainly belongs to the second one, where the supertype has fewer properties than the subtype, meaning that `T[keyof T]` here is contravariant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232290/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-tubc).